# Remove noise from characters in an image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, noise-reduction

I processed my input image and the result is below.  I just need the characters.  I tried but can't remove the noise surrounding the characters.

[image: mu.jpg]

Comment: "I processed my input image then i found it"   You found your image after processing it? Was it hidden somewhere? And how did you manage to process it if you didn't know where it was?

Comment: I meant that after processing the input image I found the mu.jpg image. And I want to remove the noise surrounding the text from mu.jpg image.

Comment: I would suggest binarizing the image and then applying morphology to remove isolated pixels and fill gaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple erosion with a small structuring element, like a 3 x 3 square may work where you would eliminate the small white noise profile and thus make the characters darker.  You can also take advantage of the fact that the areas that are black that are not characters are connected to the boundaries of the image.  You can remove these from the image by removing areas connected to the boundaries.

Therefore, perform an erosion first using [`imerode`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imerode.html), then you will need to remove the boundaries using [`imclearborder`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imclearborder.html) but this requires that the pixels touching the border are white.  Therefore, use the inverse of the output from `imerode` into the function, then inverse it again.

Something like this will work and I'll read your image from Stack Overflow directly:

```
% Read the image and threshold in case
im = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl6Y9.jpg');
im = im > 200;

% Erode
out = imerode(im, strel('square', 3));

% Remove the border and find inverse
out = ~imclearborder(~out);
```

We get this image now:

[image]

There are some isolated black holes near the B that you may not want.  You can do some additional post-processing by using [`bwareaopen`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwareaopen.html) to remove islands that are below a certain area.  I chose this to be 50 pixels from experimentation.  You'll have to do this on the inverse of the output from `imclearborder`:

```
% Read the image and threshold in case
im = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl6Y9.jpg');
im = im > 200;

% Erode
out = imerode(im, strel('square', 3));

% Remove the border
bor = imclearborder(~out);

% Remove small areas and inverse
out = ~bwareaopen(bor, 50);
```

We now get this:

[image]